# How can I insert a given date into a date textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, textbox

This is the text box:
`<asp:TextBox ID="BirthDateEdTB" runat="server" MaxLength="50" TextMode="Date" class="form-control" DateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy" DisplayDateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy" required="required"></asp:TextBox>`

I have an object of `user` that has `birthdate` from type DateTime. I took this date, and I want to show it in the textbox.

I tried looking for ideas but didn't find anything that works.

Comment: Use .Text property, something like :  `BirthDateEdTB.Text = user.BirthDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");`

Comment: It doesn't work, do you have any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code?

CONVERT(DATETIME,dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),102)

Comment: Try this on what?

Answer (score 0):

You can set "any" format you want for the text box.

However, WHEN you attempt to fill it out, you STILL want to use a iso date format.

so, say this date:

```
        DateTime dtBirth = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1);

        BirthDateEdTB.Text = dtBirth.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

So, while you have a forced/custom format of dd/MM/yyyy, you STILL are to feed the control a iso date format (like yyyy-MM-dd).